# Can I hide the artwork from the received embed code when calling SoundCloud oEmbed?

Tags: api, iframe, soundcloud, oembed

Is there any way to send a parameter to `/oembed` so that the artwork will not be shown in the received embed code?

I am thinking about rewriting the `src` attribute of the iframe in the response `html` value, but I'd rather not resort to such a hack.

Also, is it safe to assume that the iframe `src` contains `/track/` if (and only if) it's a track?

What I want to achieve is a player that displays artwork for all content types except track, where I want to hide it. My solution would be to look at the received src attribute and set `show_artwork=false` on it if it's a track.

Does this seem like a very bad idea? :)

Answer (score 3):

I need this too. A while ago, it had worked while I included show_artwork=false in my oembed request.

Eg.

```
http://soundcloud.com/oembed?url=http%3A//soundcloud.com/xxx/xxxx&format=json&show_artwork=false&auto_play=false
```

However, Soundcloud seems to have made some changes to their oembed api, and now even when I specify that, the returned code has show_artwork=true specified regardless.

I think we might have to make a feature request to Soundcloud about this.

Sure, we can edit the received results, and it will work, but that definitely not a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, show_artwork is a missing oembed parameter: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#oembed